# How do users load files to StreamingAssets?

Tags: uwp, hololens, mrtk

Is it possible to have a folder in the directory that user has permission to copy anything they like? I am working on HoloLens and want custom 3d object users have, to be used in the application.

Comment: for File access permissions please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

HoloLens apps are just UWP apps, so they have same file read/write permissions as UWP apps on Windows. You can configure your app to be able to write to certain folders, and the UWP has permission to write to some folders (like the application data folder) by default. Read about [UWP file access permissions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).